# Searching for the instance of global variable $Label in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, global-variables, apex-code, visualforce

My code in gobal footer component -

```
   <div id="copyright">
            &copy; {!$Label.copyright}
          </div>
```

It is displaying in page`"© Copyright 2012 "`

I am new in Salesforce. I just want to modified text with

```
"© Copyright 2013 "
```

In place of 2012 I want to use 2013...

What I have tried ??

1. Checked custom label
2. `$Label` is global variable search for copyright...

Please help me if I missed some basic part to check !!

Thanks!!

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12568/need-to-modified-variable-value-in-visualforce-apex-salesforce

Comment: @eyescream Thank you I got solution !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Need to modified variable value in visualforce/apex/salesforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12568/need-to-modified-variable-value-in-visualforce-apex-salesforce/12569#12569) by [rao](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/582/rao):

> If you go to `setup--> create--> custom labels` you should see a label by name copyright click on it and the value should say "copyright 2012...." change the value there to 2013.
>
> Hope this helps
>
> **UPDATE:**
>
> check this out if you are looking here:
>   [image]
>
> [image]
>
> **One final check /suggestion check your view and try to see if it is showing all the custom labels and not filtered.**
>
> [image]

This is the solution !!
Thanks !!